# Nitrous.IO -- Only able to Preview Default webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It was fairly easy to get things set up for the RubyonRails environment in the Nitrous.IO box, but I am having problems with Preview (the browser utility on the site) to see the apps that seem to be running with the `$ rails server` command.

My installation shows I have the following installed:

```
   -  ruby 2.1.1p76
   -  Rails 4.1.0
   -  git version 2.0.0
   -  SQLite3
```

When I try to  'Preview'  the application running on WEBrick,
    I get a default webpage, which says,

```
 Routes are set up in the config/routes.rb
  running in development mode and haven't set a root route yet.
```

I checked the  config/routes.rb  file in the  Nitrous.IO  IDE,
      and it has the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw.do
        resources :comments  (from  $ rails generate scaffold comment post_id:integer /
                                       body:text   [this was second of two commands] )
        resources :posts     ( $ rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text /
                                         [this was run  1st  of these  two commands] )
                 ( post and comment database tables created with:  $ rake db:migrate )

        # lines 6 -> 59 are comments giving coding examples of routes) 

        end
```

Any idea on what I need to do in order to 'Preview' development apps ??

Answer (score 0):

Perform the Preview 3000.
You get standard info that app is running
In the browser's address bar add "/(the route you need)" (well without quotes).
In my case it looks like this:
http://blog-137119.euw1-2.nitrousbox.com/comments#index
The "comments#index" was the route I needed.
HTH
/Jacek